# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 occuring in my Activity's Adapter

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, indexing, android-activity, android-adapter

When I started the MainActivity, my app crashed and returns the error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 on my stack trace.
Here's my adapter code:

```
class MainAdapter: PagingDataAdapter<ListStoryItem, MainAdapter.MyViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {

    private val listStories = ArrayList<ListStoryItem>()
    private lateinit var onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback

    class MyViewHolder(var binding: StoryItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val binding = StoryItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listStories.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setListStories(stories: List<ListStoryItem>) {
        listStories.clear()
        listStories.addAll(stories)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val (photoUrl, createdAt, name, description, _) = listStories[position]
            holder.binding.tvName.text = name
            holder.binding.tvStory.text = description
            val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
            val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
            val date = inputFormat.parse(createdAt)
            val formattedDateTimeString = outputFormat.format(date)

            holder.binding.tvDate.text = formattedDateTimeString
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
                .load(photoUrl)
                .into(holder.binding.imageView2)
            holder.binding.imageView2.setOnClickListener{
                onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(listStories[holder.adapterPosition])
        }
    }

    fun setOnItemClickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback) {
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback
    }

    interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(data: ListStoryItem)
    }

    companion object {
        private val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ListStoryItem>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ListStoryItem, newItem: ListStoryItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ListStoryItem, newItem: ListStoryItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The stacktrace leads to the `onBindViewHolder()` part of the `val (photoUrl, createdAt, name, description, _) = listStories[position]`. I'm guessing my `setListStories()` function causing the list to be empty. But I couldn't find out why the error occurred. This is the stacktrace :
[image: Stacktrace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `PagingAdapter`, best way to update is to use `adapter.submitData()` with `PageData<T>` instead of `List` and to read the item in `onBindViewHolder` you should use `getItem(position)` rather than using your local `List` as data holder! Refer here [PagingDataAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter)